# Testdriven.net not available in the right-click context menu

Tags: testdriven.net

Testdriven.net **not** available in the right-click context  menu??

Comment: TestDriven.Net not installed??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Check which edition of Visual Studio you have - you cannot install add-ins to Visual Studio Express editions.
2. Check you have actually installed TestDriven.Net.
3. Check the TestDriven.Net add-in is enabled in Visual Studio by going to `Tools -> Add-in Manager` and making sure the checkbox next to it is ticked, and that the `Startup` checkbox is also ticked.

Comment: `you cannot install add-ins to Visual Studio Express editions.` - that's contrary to what their own website says: `It supports all versions of Microsoft Visual Studio` as well as `TestDriven.Net is compatible with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010-2003 running on Windows 7, Vista, XP and Windows Server 2008-2000` etc. No indication whatsoever that Express editions are not supported.

Comment: @Morawski - Visual Studio Express editions do not support or allow add-ins. There was a bit of a scuffle a few years back when Jamie Cansdale (who writes TestDriven.Net) made it work and Microsoft forced him to change it. There are several articles on the internet about this (e.g. [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/danielfe/archive/2007/05/31/visual-studio-express-and-testdriven-net.aspx) and [this](http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/06/TestDriven-Express-Emails)). So while the site doesn't say that Express editions are not supported, they _really_ are not supported.

Comment: @adrianbanks obviously I believe you. but they definitely should say so on their website if that's the case. not everybody knows the history of their product. either they indeed support "all versions" or they don't, no matter whose fault it is.